# Slow query execution with full-text-parameter in query (c#, SQL-Server 2019)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a C#-program which queries an SQL Server database using `sqlcommand`object and retrieving the data via the `sqldatareader`.

The query contains several parameters (datetime) and one parameter is a parameter for a CONTAINS fulltext-index-search.

The part in the SQL looks like

```
and contains(md.data, @searchconditionfulltext)
```

and I set the parameter with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchconditionfulltext", 'test');
```

The query runs about 20 minutes.

If if remove the parameter and insert the search-word directly in the SQL like

```
and contains(md.data, 'test')
```

then it finish in about 2 seconds.

Why?

Comment: Probably parameter sniffing - [show us your execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: @TomTom that comment is a bit rude. Asking for a mcve is totally fine, but try not to be so harsh

Comment: @TomTom I think you might need to revise your understanding of [arrogant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/arrogant), too